# Search in Flutter Chat using ConnectyCube

Tags: flutter

I am using connecty cube for a chat in my flutter App. I want to search the user list. Like Whatsapp search option. Connecty Cube provider developer guide code. but I can't understand how it works. Please Help me I am Stuck.

Connecty Cube Search Code:

```
GlobalSearchParams additionalParams = GlobalSearchParams();
additionalParams.limit = 3;
additionalParams.endDate = DateTime(2020, 1, 1);
additionalParams.startDate = DateTime.now();
additionalParams.dialogIds = ["5e3438c7ca8bf479f704560c"];

searchText("Search query", additionalParams.getSearchParams())
    .then((globalSearchResult) {})
    .catchError((error) {});
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I get result by just removing additionalParams.endDate = DateTime(2020, 1, 1);
additionalParams.startDate = DateTime.now();
I Don't know whats the problem with this. but it works for me